# Java with sonar: reduce complexity of method

Tags: java

```
public Meteo getMeteoTorneo() {
    
    Meteo meteo = new Meteo(cittaString);
    
    Document doc = null;
    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.ilmeteo.it/meteo/" + torneo.getCitta()).get();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Elements newsHeadlines = doc.getElementsByTag("li");
    for (Element headline : newsHeadlines) {
        if (headline.text().split(" ").length > 2) {
            String tmax = headline.getElementsByClass("tmax").text();
            String tmin = headline.getElementsByClass("tmin").text();
            String giorno = headline.getElementsByTag("span").first() != null ? headline.getElementsByTag("span").first().text() : "";
            boolean rain  = headline.getElementsByClass("s flag_pioggia").isEmpty();
            boolean nuvoloso  = headline.getElementsByClass("s ss3").isEmpty();
            boolean sole  = headline.getElementsByClass("s ss1").isEmpty();
            if(controllaTemp(tmin, tmax))
                continue;

            if((controllaData() && (giorno.split(" ")[1].equals(""+torneo.getData().getDayOfMonth())))){
                    if(!rain)
                        meteo.setT("1");
                    else if(!nuvoloso)
                        meteo.setT("2");
                    else if(!sole)
                        meteo.setT("3");
                    meteo.settMin(tmin);
                    meteo.settMax(tmax);
                    
                }
            
        }
    }
    return meteo;

}
```

Hi, I have a problem with this method. Sonar tells me to reduce its Cognitive Complexity from 21 to the 15 allowed, but I have no idea what I have to do, because I can remove nothing. Could you suggest something? Thanks

Comment: Refactor. it is not about "removing" things, but restructuring things. For example, the outermost `if` looks like it could be moved in a separate method.

Comment: Yeah, it's better to quit early than write nested branches - discard cases first, then proceed with code as normal. It's called short-circuiting. This is not an error, it's a warning - sometimes warnings are crap. But I generally advise from what you do in line with assigning `giorno` - you evaluate things twice. Do yourself a favor and use variables...

Comment: Take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/66937330/5932611

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to remove anything, you can extract the information inside of the "for" in a method, like this:

```
public Meteo getMeteoTorneo() {

    Meteo meteo = new Meteo(cittaString);

    Document doc = null;
    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.ilmeteo.it/meteo/" + torneo.getCitta()).get();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Elements newsHeadlines = doc.getElementsByTag("li");
    for (Element headline : newsHeadlines) {
        if (headline.text().split(" ").length > 2) {
            updateMeteo(headline, meteo)
        }
    }
    return meteo;
}

private void updateMeteo(Element headline, Meteo meteo) {
    String tmax = headline.getElementsByClass("tmax").text();
    String tmin = headline.getElementsByClass("tmin").text();
    String giorno = headline.getElementsByTag("span").first() != null ? headline.getElementsByTag("span").first().text() : "";
    boolean rain  = headline.getElementsByClass("s flag_pioggia").isEmpty();
    boolean nuvoloso  = headline.getElementsByClass("s ss3").isEmpty();
    boolean sole  = headline.getElementsByClass("s ss1").isEmpty();
    if(controllaTemp(tmin, tmax))
        return;

    if((controllaData() && (giorno.split(" ")[1].equals(""+torneo.getData().getDayOfMonth())))){
        if(!rain)
            meteo.setT("1");
        else if(!nuvoloso)
            meteo.setT("2");
        else if(!sole)
            meteo.setT("3");
            meteo.settMin(tmin);
            meteo.settMax(tmax);          
    }
}
```

Now if you look at it, the `meteo` object would always set the same variables (T, Min and Max). So probably is better to get those three elements and set them at the end (using a `Tuple3` or, even better, your own class)